# Does D3 transition work on nodejs?

Tags: node.js, d3.js

I am using code provided by in link https://gist.github.com/Caged/6407459.
SVG is generated fine and shown on browser. However I am not able to use .transition and .on functions of D3 in this code. Does these function work with nodejs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gist you link to is meant for creating static SVG markup and sending them to the client. Hence, the client (browser) only gets the SVG markup sans any Javascript. You cannot bind event handlers to the markup on the server; that task must be done by the browser on the client side. You will have to ship some javascript code to the client.

As for the transitions, since D3 implements transitions via javascript, these will also not be sent to the client. There are ways of animating the SVG using CSS3 and SMIL which can be rendered on the server but I suspect it would be easier to send code to the client for the kind of animations you need.

What you are trying to do is akin to opening the rendered SVG in Illustrator or Inkscape, and asking whether the transitions and callbacks will still work.